# ASP.NET Identity в микросервисной архитектуре

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2, микросервисы

Сейчас пытаюсь вынести ASP.NET Identity в нижние слои (Models и DAL) и возник такой вопрос, а нельзя ли использовать ASP.NET Identity как микросервис, то есть внешний поставщик авторизации?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Напрямую - нет, нельзя. И даже уровнем ниже вы ее не затащите. Просто потому что ASP.NET Identity работает с такими сущностями как HTTP-запрос и конфигурацией веб-сервера.

Если же ненапрямую - то можно сделать так. Разворачиваете отдельно [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3), на нем настраиваете ASP.NET Identity, а другие свои приложения цепляете к IdentityServer через OpenID-Connect.